# Pulley system for lifting device

Tags: pulleys

[image]

I'm designing a lifting device powered by a motor, i would like to know if the forces exerted by the load on pulley 1 and 2 are equal when the motor star running , or if in pulley 1 is exerted more force because the location of the load at the end of the lifting platform. The lifting platform only moves vertically, restricted by rails. What I want to know if the load will exert a perpendicular force that could create friction on the rails

Comment: as drawn there will be a rotation moment simply because the load is on one side and the pulleys on the other. Even if pulley 1 carried all the weight it will still rotate

Comment: @ratchetfreak  technically "attempt to rotate" given perfect restraining rails.  But your point is well taken.

Comment: voting to close as unclear and non-response to clarification questions.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the load will exert a moment, to study the behaviour of your system you can simply model it as a constrained beam in pure bending if the elasticity of your platform is not negligible or as a constrained rigid body. Every point of the rail is a constrained point, analyzing the strain diagrams you can compute how much perpendicular force you will have.

Comment: But if the tension along the cord keeps constant once the motor start running, how can it be that forces exerted on pulley 1and 2 be different.

Comment: Reactions are equal but different in directions. Between the 2 pulleys you will have 2 opposite bending moments.

Comment: @JorCamero whoever claimed the pulley forces are different?  The question really should be improved by showing in the graphic what keeps the platform from rotating.

Answer (score 0):

The drawing is lacking detail on how to the load and platform will not rotate.  Despite this, you can assume accelerations are zero; therefore static. The sum of the forces, and the sum of the moments in the system must equal zero.  Then a safety factor of should be computed per ASME B30.